# Differentiation of a matrix function

Tags: matrix, calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to compute the derivative (Jacobian) of the function $\mathbf{\Psi\left(\mathbf{F}\right)}$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{F}$ where $\mathbf{F}$ is a 2x2 matrix and $G$ and $v$ are just real constants;

$$
    \begin{align}
    \Psi(\mathbf{F}) &= \frac{\mu}{2} \left(     \text{tr}\left(\mathbf{F}^\top \mathbf{F}\right)-2\right)-    \mu\log(\text{det}\left(\mathbf{F}\right)) + \frac{\lambda}    {2}\log^2\left({\text{det}\left(\mathbf{F}\right)}\right)\\
    \mu &= \frac{G}{2\left(1+v\right)}\\
    \lambda &= \frac{Gv}{(1+v)(1-2v)}\\\\
    G, v &\in {\rm I\!R}\\
    \mathbf{F} &\in {\rm I\!R}^{2\times2}\\\\
    \frac{\partial\mathbf{\Psi}}{\partial\mathbf{F}} &= \text{?}
    \end{align}
$$

I've come up with the following formula for MMA, but I'm not sure if it produces the correct result;

```
F = Array[a, {2, 2}]

D[
   G/(2*(1 + v))             * (Tr[Transpose[F]*F] - 2) - 
   G/(2*(1 + v))             * Log[Det[F]] + 
   G*v/(2*(1 + v)*(1 - 2*v)) * Log[Det[F]]^2,
{F}] // MatrixForm // Simplify
```

Is there any mistake in the code? And even if there'd be no mistake, can I get a better-formatted result (maybe using matrix operations, instead of explicit usage of the matrix's elements, when possible)? (Please bear in mind I'm absolute beginner with Mathematica.)